# Почему не срабатывает поиск по %

Tags: sql-server

Пытаюсь получить в результате запроса данные о имени страны, столице, человеке из нее родом и его пол. Вроде бы запрос написан верно, но как только пытаюсь сделать выборку с применением Like в результате не выводится ничего.Если же убрать начало слова и оставить только % выводятся все данные но без привязки к условию. Никак не понимаю - в чем причина? Прошу объяснить  в чем моя ошибка

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountryName, CapitalName, Persons.[Name], 
Persons.Surname, Persons.Sex 
FROM dbo.Countries 
JOIN dbo.Capitals ON Countries.Capital =Capitals.Id 
JOIN dbo.Persons ON Countries.Person=Persons.Id 
JOIN dbo.Regions ON Countries.Region=Regions.Id 
WHERE Regions.Region LIKE 'А%'
GROUP BY Countries.CountryName, CapitalName, Persons.[Name], Persons.Surname, Persons.Sex
```

PS в таблице "регионы" регионы начинающиеся с А точно есть.

Comment: 'А' набито в английской кодировки а регионы по русски или наоборот

Comment: Проверял-все в русской

Comment: А если `LIKE N'А%'`?

Comment: вы начните с запроса `select * from regions where region like ...` без всего остального. и какой нить `COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` явно попробуйте указать после условия

Comment: LIKE N'А%' сработало! Спасибо